# Intellij gets stuck when running tomcat since upgraded to 2018.1

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2018

I recently upgraded Intellij Ultimate to 2018.1 on Windows 10 and I experienced Keyboard issues when I run consoles in Floating Mode. The keyboard doesn't work in the main window (Backspace and Esc keys are always ignored, other keys are often ignored)

Steps to reproduce:

- Open a console (Sql, Tomcat, ..) in floating mode
- After a while the main window become partially or completely unresponsive

  - Backspace doesn't work in the editor on the main window (for example editing a java class)
  - Mouse doesn't work on the main window
  - Sometimes all keys don't work (you cannot write in the main window)
  - The main window top bar flickers
  - Sometimes intellij gets completely stuck and I need to kill it
- Dock the console to the main window or make it windowed

  - Situation is back to normal

Comment: If I close the "Run" console (the one with the Tomcat output) the main bar stops flickering and keyboards gets back to normal.
Note: My application isn't logging much, so it isn't the frequency of the log causing the issue.

Comment: [1] Open up Windows Task Manager to see if there is any unexpected resource usage while Tomcat is running. [2] Did you check for any errors in Tomcat's log? [3] Does the mouse remain responsive while you have problems with the keyboard? [4] Your comment is relevant and useful, but it would be better to update your post with that information.

Comment: Please raise a ticket at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Comment: I opened this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189449

Comment: The JetBrains ticket you raised is very different to your post.

Comment: @skomisa you're right, I changed the description so that it is the same I put in the ticket.